# Share wireless connection with ethernet device - Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian)

Tags: linux, networking

I would like to share a internet connection to a computer which is connected to Raspberry Pi 3 via ethernet cable. I am using WIFI connection for my Raspberry.

I have already set the IP settings on other computer but it does not work like when you are connecting two computers.

I need static IP on Raspberry and on other computer. I have already set that Raspberry has static IP (wlan0), but when I set ethernet (eth0) to static IP, internet on Raspberry stops working.

[That is how my network should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fojIm.png)

[ifconfig from Raspberry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X63q3.jpg)

Thank you for your help, BR Matevz

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you need to use a network range for the network between the computer and the Raspberry pi.  The network between the router and Raspberry is 192.168.50.0/24
The network between the computer should be something different, for example it could be:  192.168.51.0/24
The Raspberry pi could then be 192.168.51.1 and the computer could be 192.168.51.2

You would then have to use IP forwarding on the PI and possibly NAT as well.